# Python threading - Run function at certain times

Tags: python, timer, python-multithreading

I have a set of data like

```
schedule = [(2, 5),
            (4, 6),
            (10, 2)]
```

with the first element of each tuple being a time (in seconds) and the second element being a value.

I would like to start a separate thread which tracks the time and at each scheduled time runs some arbitrary function `func(value)`.

What is the cleanest way to do this? I could create a Timer object for each scheduled time, but that seems sloppy.

edit: You can assume the times are in ascending order

Comment: Are the times necessarily in ascending order?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorting them from the start, but if there is a robust solution that doesn't make the assumption that they are sorted, that is great too

Comment: Probably overkill but if this is for a big project or might grow, consider [APScheduler](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/v3.2.0/)

Comment: Yeah, this is a small part of a small project that probably wont go anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need them to be in separate threads then a Timer object or as a commenter pointed out APScheduler. If you want to do the threading manually you could also use sched. They added support for threads in version 3.3. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html)

Comment: sched (in a separate thread)  worked perfectly here. Just what I needed.